# phpunit Google_Client mock

Tags: php, unit-testing, google-analytics, phpunit, google-analytics-api

Attempting to do some unit testing for a GA processing class, but I can't figure out how to correctly mock the client object.  I'm getting this error with the mock code below.

`Call to undefined method Google_Client::__phpunit_cleanup()`

```
public function getMockGaClient() {
    return $this->getMockBuilder('Google_Client')
        ->setMockClassName('Google_Client')
        ->getMock();
}
```

to be a bit preemptive, I'm setting the mock name so it passes a parameter check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$googleClientMock = $this->createMock(Google_Client::class);
$googleClientMock->expects(static::once())->method('setScopes')
->with([
    Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS,
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE
]);
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your code to help other people understand what you are doing.